# A question about Thermodynamics

Tags: thermodynamics

Burning fuel in car engine produce more heat or burning that fuel in free space?

Comment: How would you burn fuel in free space? It needs *oxygen* to burn.

Answer (score 2):

Burning the fuel in car produces less heat than just burning the fuel in an open container because in an engine some of the energy produced by combustion goes into doing work on the car. In an open container all the energy appears as heat.

However the energy that goes into doing work on the car ends up as heat eventually because the car dissipates the energy as friction and aerodynamic drag. So in both cases all the energy ends up as heat eventually. It just takes a slightly different route in the two cases.